# How to get the price of my Associated products in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am using magento 1.4.1

I have a configured product set up with 2 associated products. 
Here\\’s an example of my scenario right now.

I have set up a configurable product named SHOE and it has an associated product BIG SHOE & SMALL SHOE. 
I set up a pricing of the configurable product shoe. It has the price. $80. 
I also set up a $20 price of my associated product BIG SHOE and a $10 on SMALL SHOE.

When I try to purchase SMALL SHOE, i\\’m getting the price of the configurable product SHOE and that\\’s $80. Same thing when I purchased BIG SHOE. I want to get the price of the associated product and this isn\\’t happening

How would I do that?

Please Help me. Thanks in advance and Have a great Day!

Thanks!

How to get the price of my Associated products

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need Simple Configurable Products module (SCP):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Matt+Dean/extension/596/simple-configurable-products

Comment: Sorry to mod your answer down for that - I live in hope of a decent configurables update module and it is just not forthcoming!

Comment: https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple - can always contribute for such ;) I've used in the past and yes there are some issues with it but It can serve a purpose given the requirements.

Comment: unfortunately, SCP does not work with Magento CE 1.6...
does anyone know of another free extension that does the job?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get SCP to work in 1.7.0.2

So I made up this:

1)
Go to app/design/frontend/*your_theme*/default/template/catalog/product/price.phtml
Around line 201 look for $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, true)

2)
outcomment it and place this instead

```
<?php
// prices of child products /////////////////////////////////////////////////
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
    $_configurable = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProductIds();
    echo '<b>ab '.number_format(Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($_configurable[0], 'price'), 2, ',', '').' €</b>';
endif;
// prices of child products /////////////////////////////////////////////////
?>
```